# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate cannot open files on a network share

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have been experiencing issues with VS 2013 Ultimate where students cannot Open Website files that are stored on a network share. There was no issue with VS2010 opening the same files.

The PCs are on our Students domain, they can access their files at anytime, it is only when opening from within VS 2013 that it locks up the application.

To get around this, I copied the files to the desktop and they opened fine, so it seems the application has issues with network share files. I asked the students to retry opening the file on the network share and it works. It is just initially it locks up.

Can you please advise if you know of any issues with the program that might cause this?

Thanks!!

*Windows 8.1, Intel i7s, 8/16gb ram
Software has been tested on full install with all options and Update 2 included.
**Also installed Update 5, issue still remains

Comment: WAG, but try mapping the network share to a drive letter, say N:.  Then try to open the file through the N drive.

Comment: The drives are automatically mapped to the Z: drive, when the students login, it shows up.

Comment: The files are downloaded from the student assignment website, they save it to the Z: drive as it follows them to whatever PC they login to. Open Visual Studio 2013 and File, Open Website and select the lab folder that they downloaded and unzipped. Press Open and application is not responding.